# How to write back nested properties with Angular reactive forms?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

How to populate properties with Angular reactive forms?

Today I started to use reactive forms a little more intensively and immediately encountered a problem of understanding. Before I always wrote my forms with `ngModel` and built something like this:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="data.name" />
<input [(ngModel)]="data.setings.property1" />
<input [(ngModel)]="data.setings.property2" />
```

With reactive forms it would look like this:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
    <input formControlName="name" />
    <input formControlName="property1" />
    <input formControlName="property2" />
</form>

** Compoennt Init **

this.myForm = this.fb.group({
    name: new FormControl({ value: this.data.name }, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]),
    property1: new FormControl({ value: this.data.setings.property1 }, Validators.required),
    property2: new FormControl({ value: this.data.setings.property2 }, Validators.required),
})
```

So far so good. My problem now is: how do I get the changed values back to `this.data`? The only thing I found is something like:

```
this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
    ....
});
```

Since my real data structure is relatively complex and contains many nested properties, I would now have to assign everything manually, a'la:

```
if (val == 'property1')
    data.setings.property1 = val;
else if 
    ...
```

That seems very complicated to me. Since something like this can be done quickly and easily with `ngModel`, I'm wondering whether there isn't a similarly comfortable option for reactive forms?

Answer (score 4):

You can use nested `FormGroup`s

See this example using [FormGroupName](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroupName)

This way, when instantiating the form:

```js
form = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormGroup({
      first: new FormControl('Nancy', Validators.minLength(2)),
      last: new FormControl('Drew', Validators.required)
    }),
    email: new FormControl()
});
```

in the HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
      <p *ngIf="name.invalid">Name is invalid.</p>

      <div formGroupName="name">
        <input formControlName="first" placeholder="First name">
        <input formControlName="last" placeholder="Last name">
      </div>
      <input formControlName="email" placeholder="Email">
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

You can retrieve the structure

```js
{
   name: {
      first: string,
      last: string,
   },
   email: string,
}
```

when doing `form.value`.

Answer (score -1):

I get the value as follows: this.myForm.get("property1").value

Comment: This is not the question. The question is: how to get the form values back to the object where they came from. On flat objects it is clear ans simple, but how to do if these data structure is very complex and nested

Comment: If the attributes of the object have the same names as the form, you can do the following: `objectName: {
                ...formName
            }`  or if they are not the same names `object.atributte = form.atributte`

Comment: I response your question ? (Sorry for the bad interpret you, my english is bad)